# How to encode a bit literal in a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view which unions multiple tables. One table has a bit column called VisibleToCustomer. One of the other tables does not have this, and I want to hard code it in the view. I can do this with strings:-

```
SELECT  'Fred' "VisibleToCustomer", ....
```

or even ints

```
SELECT  1 "VisibleToCustomer", ....
```

but how do I do it with a bit? I.e. I want to do something like

```
SELECT  true "VisibleToCustomer", ....
```

but obviously the above doesn't work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
 SELECT  'true' AS "VisibleToCustomer"
```

bit has [higher data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than varchar so this will cast correctly.

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT) AS "VisibleToCustomer"
UNION ALL
SELECT 'false'
```

Returns

```
+-------------------+
| VisibleToCustomer |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
|                 0 |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Huge thanks for such a quick and comprehensive reply, works a treat!

Answer (score 3):

The three possible values for bit literals:
`select cast(1 as bit), cast(0 as bit), cast(null as bit)`

Note: Any non zero values will become `1` when cast to bit, `CAST(-1.2e-33 AS BIT)`. I would recommend against writing a bit literal that way.

Comment: And `CAST('true' AS BIT), CAST('false' AS BIT)`

Comment: @MartinSmith, I did not know that. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply, used Martins but yours was good also!

Comment: Also numeric string literals, as well as + and -, which are both zero:
CAST('1' AS BIT), CAST('0000' AS BIT), CAST('-' AS BIT), CAST('+' AS BIT).